# Error while excuting a simple boost thread program

Tags: c++, boost-thread

Could you tell mw what is the problem with the below boost::thread program

```
#include<iostream>
#include<boost/thread/thread.hpp>

boost::mutex mutex;

class A
{
public:
A() : a(0) {}

void operator()()
{
          boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mutex);

}
private:
int a;
```

};

```
int main()
{
    boost::thread thr1(A());
    boost::thread thr2(A());
    thr1.join();
    thr2.join();
```

}

I get the error message:
error: request for member 'join' in 'thr1', which is of non-class type           'boost::thread()(A (*)())'
BoostThread2.cpp:30: error: request for member 'join' in 'thr2', which is of non-class type 'boost::thread ()(A (*)())'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have stumbled on something wonderfully known as the [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).  The quickest way to fix that is to add an extra set of parentheses:

```
boost::thread thr1((A()));
```

You can also introduce a temporary:

```
A tmp1;
boost::thread thr1(tmp1);
```

In the most vexing parse, what you think is generating a temporary is parsed as if it's a function taking no parameters.  It then treats thr1 as a prototype to a function that takes a single parameter (which is the function mentioned previously) and returning a boost::thread.

Comment: Yeah , I just did that and it works fine, i just could not get why it behaves like that.

Comment: @EternalLearner - I just added a short summary of what is happening.  If you want a more, search for "most vexing parse" and you'll find plenty of more detailed explanations.

Answer (score 6):

This is a classic C++ trap. `thr1` is not what you think it is (a thread object). It's the declaration of a function that takes an instance of A as a parameter. Wrap it in parentheses to force the intended interpretation:

```
boost::thread thr1((A()));
boost::thread thr2((A()));
```

### The detailed explanation

Syntactically, the original syntax is equivalent to:

```
boost::thread thr1(A);
```

Why is the compiler allowed to ignore the empty parentheses? Frankly, I'm not sure — I'm not a C++ language expert — but I think it has to with the following train of thought: `A *a` = `A (*a)`, therefore `A *` = `A (*)`; likewise, `A a` = `A (a)`, therefore `A` = `A ()`.

### Look to the future!

The upcoming C++ standard will fix this as a byproduct of its new initialisation syntax:

```
boost::thread thr1{A()};
boost::thread thr2{A()};
```

Comment: Well, then isn't A() - a temporary instance of class A ?

Comment: I've amended my answer to (I hope) make it clear why this happens.